# Java create a JAR file for contrib packages in Lucene

Tags: java, svn, jar, lucene

I have downloaded the source code of [Apache Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) using Subversion.
Now I want to create a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file for a particular Java file in the contrib portion of the code.

The problem is that when I do `javac x.java` to get a class file and package it into a JAR file using `jar cf jarfile.jar x.class` the package hierarchy is not preserved in the JAR file.

What is the correct way of packaging class files into the JAR file maintaining the package hierarchy?

Particularly with Subversion checked out code is there a better way of packaging selected Java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene have [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)'s `build.xml`, you can make jar by using `ant package` at lucene source directory. For contribs there are also `contrib/contrib-build.xml`

Answer (score 1):

```
mindas:/tmp/test$ pwd
/tmp/test
mindas:/tmp/test$ ls
mindas:/tmp/test$ mkdir some
mindas:/tmp/test$ mkdir some/package
mindas:/tmp/test$ touch some/package/SomeFile.class
mindas:/tmp/test$ jar cf jarfile.jar some/package/SomeFile.class
```

That does preserve the structure.